# update single record based on date with multiple dates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to update a only one record on a specific date, where there are multiple records on that date...  It doesn't matter which one.   Below is the output I am looking for.

```
id        date        charge
01       1/1/2014     75
02       1/1/2014     0
03       1/1/2014     0
04       1/2/2014     75
05       1/3/2014     75
06       1/3/2014     0
```

it does matter which id is updated, i just need one updated on on that date.  Any suggestion, or if you could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a rather odd business requirement.  You could use `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM MyTable WHERE DATE=@theDate` to get a single ID to update.  Having said that, doing so seems unlikely to correctly solve any real-world problem I can think of.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, our business sends technicians to different sites to perform work.  Each site the individual visits, we charge a rental fee for the equipment the technician uses.  If the technician performs multiple jobs on the same site, the client is only charged the equipment rental fee once.  Make sense?

Comment: Randomly updating only one row on that given date will not accomplish what you describe.  You should look for duplicate equipment rental fees on the same date, *for the same customer*, and either zero out or delete the duplicate records that match those specific criteria.

Comment: I gotcha.  I ended up using MAX(ID), grouping by the date, then inserting into a temp table.  Then used that temp table to update the original table.  Thanks!